# How can I rewrite $I(X;Y|Z,W)$?

Tags: probability, information-theory

I can rewrite the mutual information of $I(X;Y|Z)$ to $H(Y|Z) - H(Y|X,Z)$ but how exactly can I rewrite a mutual information of the form $I(X;Y|Z,W)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing. Just think of $(Z,W)$ of a single (multidimensional) variable. Then

$$I(X;Y|Z,W)=H(Y|Z,W) - H(Y|X,Z,W)$$